# "Connection Refused" error with MSS SIP servlet over WSS

Tags: restcomm

I would like to ask for help.

I am using the `mss-4.0.21-wildfly-8.2.1.Final` server and the SIP servlet `B2B WebSocket sample` with some small changes in order to use the Doubango sipML5 client for registering and making call.

When I use the `ws` protocol, my servlet works fine, I can register and make call with Doubango sipML5 client.

When I use the `wss` protocol, the register function works fine, but I get the error "Connection Refused" while trying to make call. I checked my servlet code and found that the "Connection Refused" error is at this line `outRequest.send();`. I think the problem is that my servlet cannot send the INVITE request to callee over `wss` because it is refused. Now I have no idea about how to solve this problem.

Thus, I would like to ask for any idea about this problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Doubango sipML5, I use the Olympus which is the RestComm WebRTC Application, and everything works fine now.